# Am unable to get more than 1MB file from Iphone to service using POST functionality of IPhone

Tags: php, iphone, ios, xml

Here IPhone Users sends data to service using POST method so if service receives data am checking whether it is from POST r not?

```
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
```

If POST am getting the contents from it using file_get_contents('php://input'); but my problem is am unable to get data above 1MB.....

```
        $postText = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

am putting the contents into one .xml file

```
        file_put_contents("geopost1.xml", $postText);
```

from that .xml file am loading the data into one variable named $xml

```
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("geopost1.xml");
```

from that variable am retrieving the data i needed to send to DB...Using Below flow....

```
        if ($xml->getName() == "Details") {
            foreach ($xml->children() as $Timesheet) {
                $count = 0;


                if ($Timesheet->getName() == "TimeSheet") {
                    foreach ($Timesheet->children() as $child) {

                        $count++;

                        switch ($count) {
                            case 4:
                                if ($child->getName() == "Image") {
                                    if ($child) {
                                        $imgdata = base64_decode($child);

                                        $f = finfo_open();

                                        $mime_type = finfo_buffer($f, $imgdata, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

                                        $i = strpos($mime_type, '/');
                                        $type = substr($mime_type, $i + 1);
                                        $Image1 = time() . '.' . $type;
                                        file_put_contents('files/' . $Image1, $imgdata);
                                        $Image = 'files/' . time() . '.' . $type;
                                    }
```

Comment: what is the value of upload_max_filesize  n your php.ini

Comment: nope , this will be in your php installation folder

Comment: upload_max_filesize = 999M; this is the limit

Comment: sry it is 2M so i made it as 999M

Comment: try echoing $xml and see if the data has been loaded fully

Comment: also if you have a setting in php.ini this will not reflect until you restart apache

Comment: it is a service right so how can i know if i echo $xml?

Comment: am having a doubt if i though change the limit how the service can know about it?generally it executes the files hosted in particular site na so there php.ini file will not present?

Comment: This is most likely duplicate material. Please search for this PHP configuration issue first on site. There is no need to duplicate existing Q&A only because you ran into the *same* problem. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/help -  And for the book: There is also no need that you duplicate your own your own: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18867864/367456

Comment: @hakre so how can i use stream_copy_to_stream() in my code?

Comment: @mounisweety: As outlined in the manual (or as we say: just by the book).

Comment: but how can i save the data copied using strem_copy_to_stream() in geopost1.xml file